# MATLAB: Getting access to private class members dynamically

Tags: matlab, oop

I am designing a platform for development that a team of people will use. This team represents both the developers and users. They will both be using the platform for real-world actions, and developing new code for the platform. I am using MATLAB's object-oriented programming, and Subversion for version control. My problem is the following:

1. I want to keep public interfaces at a minimum to preserve encapsulation and keep the system modular. I will do this by only making relevant class-members public.
2. If some complicated process fails, it may not be obvious why, especially if it fails due to a private class-member. If it took an hour or more before the failure point, I don't want the developers/users to have to re-run the code with a break-point to find out what was going on.
3. If a developer wants to try a new idea that involves a private class-member, they could check out a branch of the software and do whatever they want, but this requires time and planning. It is not something they can do at 'run-time'.
4. I would like a way of temporarily gaining access to private class-members, through a back-door, that would allow developers and users to gain access dynamically.

It is possible that this question stems from some naivete on my part. I am not a software engineer, I just happen to be the most experienced programmer on my team. Therefore, I am also looking for possible reasons why I shouldn't do this. Is there a better way of thinking about this problem?

```
classdef DevTest

    properties (Access = private)
        privateProp = 'This property is private';
    end

    methods (Access = private)
        function privateMethod(This)
            disp('You''ve gained access to a private method!')
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see the point, here... Why bother writing OO code at all if you're then going to write code to break MATLAB's OO paradigm? Sounds like inviting trouble to me... Perhaps if you provided a less abstract description of your end-goal it might be easier to help you come up with a tangible design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris, please don't do this - it's a really bad idea, and it will not make life easier for you or your developers.

If you're designing something purely for other developers, trust them to be able to make changes and to not mess things up. If you're designing something for users, lock it down to provide access only to the things they need.

If you're working with a team of developers designing something for users, then I hope you're using a version control system, right?

If not, then stop all work right now, get it into version control, and start using it.

Keep the main trunk locked down for users, with methods and properties as private as appropriate. If one of your developers wishes to experiment with something by making it public, they can check out a private branch and make as many changes as they like without you worrying that they'll "forget to change it back" (that phrase rang alarm bells for me, and made me think you might not be using version control). If their experiments prove useful and you can justify making some method or property public for users, then merge their changes back into the trunk.

PS If you really want to pursue your design, you might consider making your developer methods `Hidden`, so that other users can't see the secret backdoor.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Sam. We are using version control, but your point is well-taken.

Comment: Sam, I clarified my question. Does it change your answer in any way?

Comment: I think that's a good clarification, but I don't think my answer changes substantially. I would still suggest to you that while 1 is a great idea, 4 is a bad idea. 2 is a general issue that can be addressed with good debugging practices (for example, you could implement a logger class, with different logging levels for debug and regular runs - Google log4m for an example on MATLABCentral). I'm still not sure what the issue quite is with 3 - does it require a lot of time and planning to create and check out a dev branch?

Comment: Here's a direct link to log4m: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37701-log4m-a-powerful-and-simple-logger-for-matlab I haven't used it myself directly as I wrote my own logger class, but from the look of it you could modify it for your own needs quite easily.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea. I will create a class called `Developer` which will contain a `Developable` object as a property. The interface called `Developable` would have 3 abstract methods, `getProperty`, `setProperty`, and `meval`. I would restrict access to these methods to `Developable` and `Developer`. Here's some sample code below:

The `classdef` for `Developable`

```
classdef (Abstract) Developable < handle

    methods (Abstract, Access = {?Developable, ?Developer})
        propVal = getProperty(This, propName)

        This = setProperty(This, propName, propVal)

        varargout = meval(This, methodName, varargin)
    end

end
```

and for `Developer`

```
classdef Developer < handle

    properties
        DevObj@Developable
    end

    methods
        function This = Developer(DevObj)
            if isa(DevObj, 'Developable')
                This.DevObj = DevObj;
                warnId = '''Developer:debugUseOnly''';
                warnMessage = ['''The Developer class should only be used ' ...
                    'temporarily to gain access to private and ' ...
                    'protected class members. Do not use in any ' ...
                    'permanent manner. Instead contact the owner ' ...
                    'of the class you wish to modify, and work out a ' ...
                    'solution.'''];
                warnStr = ['warning(' warnId ',' warnMessage ')'];
                evalin('caller', warnStr)
            else
                errorId = 'Developer:nonDevelopableObject';
                errorMsg = 'DevObj must be a Developable Object';
                error(errorId, errorMsg)
            end
        end

        function propVal = getProperty(This, propName)
            propVal = This.DevObj.getProperty(propName);
        end

        function setProperty(This, propName, propVal)
            This.DevObj.setProperty(propName, propVal);
        end

        function varargout = meval(This, methodName, varargin)
            if nargout > 0
                out = cell(1, nargout);
                [out{:}] = This.DevObj.meval(methodName, varargin{:});
                varargout = out;
            else
                This.DevObj.meval(methodName, varargin{:});
            end
        end

    end

end
```

This seems to work for me, but there are some problems with it:

- Every subclass has to implement the three methods from `Developable`, but the code contained in these methods will be pretty much the same in every instance.
- Once I start inheriting from `Developable` classes, things will start getting complicated.
- I haven't figured out how to use this to gain access to static methods.

Does anyone have a better way to solve my problem, or to address some of the problems I've listed above?

Here's an example `Developable` class:

```
classdef DevTest < Developable

    properties (Access = private)
        privateProp = 'This property is private';
    end

    methods (Access = private)
        function privateMethod(This)
            disp('You''ve gained access to a private method!')
        end
    end

    methods (Access = {?Developable, ?Developer})
        function propVal = getProperty(This, propName)
            propVal = This.(propName);
        end

        function This = setProperty(This, propName, propVal)
            This.(propName) = propVal;
        end

        function varargout = meval(This, methodName, varargin)
            if nargout > 0
                varargout = cell(nargout, 1);
                [varargout{:}] = This.(methodName)(varargin{:});
            else
                This.(methodName)(varargin{:});
            end
        end
    end
end
```